# Session Fixation PoC

Tags: web-application, session-fixation

I wonder what Session Fixation exploit possibilities still exist today in case the website does not change the Session-ID in a cookie after login other than the following:

1. XSS
2. MiTM
3. open redirect vuln

We've encountered a customer website which has the issue and would like to design a PoC to exploit it.

Comment: copying the cookie?